# Call a controller function in a component's templateUrl

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, angularjs-components, angularjs-material

Is there a way to call a controller's function inside a component that's encapsulated inside a div, which is already run by this controller?

**The component:**

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.component('taxiCard', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/taxi.html',
    bindings: { 
        taxi: '=' ,
        cancelTaxi: '='
    },
})
```

**The controller's function that I want to use in the template:**

```
$scope.cancelTaxi = (taxi, id) => {
   console.log('cancelling..')
   taxi.available = true;
   taxi.history.unshift(cancel);
   dataFactory.updateTaxi(id, taxi).then(function(response){ 
   });
}
```

**The component's templateUrl:**

```
<md-card style="width: 300px;">
{{$ctrl.taxi._id}}
<md-button ng-show="$ctrl.taxi.available" ng-href="#!/taxies/rent/{{$ctrl.taxi._id}}">Najem</md-button> <!-- show if taxi.available -->
<md-button ng-hide="$ctrl.taxi.available" ng-click="$ctrl.cancelTaxi($ctrl.taxi, $ctrl.taxi._id)" type="submit">Preklici</md-button><!-- show if !taxi.available, torej cancel ce je rentan atm-->
<img ng-src="{{$ctrl.taxi.photo_url}}" class="md-card-image" alt="$ctrl.taxi.name" style="height:250px">
<md-card-title>
    <md-card-title-text>
    <span class="md-headline">{{$ctrl.taxi.name}}</span>
    </md-card-title-text>
</md-card-title>
<md-card-content>
    Leto izdelave: {{$ctrl.taxi.year}} <br>
    Max potnikov: {{$ctrl.taxi.max_p}} <br>
    Max hitrost: {{$ctrl.taxi.max_s}} <br>
</md-card-content>
<md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <md-button ng-href="#!/taxies/details/{{$ctrl.taxi._id}}">Podrobnosti</md-button>
</md-card-actions>
```

**Where I'm using the component:**

```
<div class="md-padding" layout="row" ng-init="getTaxies()" layout-wrap>
<div ng-repeat="taxi in taxies">
    <a href="#!" ng-click="removeTaxi(taxi._id)">Delete</a>
    <taxi-card  taxi="taxi" 
                cancelTaxi="cancelTaxi">
    </taxi-card>   
</div>
```

To clarify; cancelTaxi is a function that's part of the TaxiesController, which is already run on the html site, where i use the . All the attributes in the templateUrl are displaying properly, but I don't know how to get the function to cancel the taxi on clicking the button working.

Oh yes, I did a console.log in the function and it doesn't even register it...

Thank you for your time and input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the component's scope is isolated. You can do two things:

---

Convert your `TaxiesController` to a component, and `require` it in `taxiCard`.

```
.component('taxiCard', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/taxi.html',
    require: {
        TaxiesController: '^TaxiesController' // ^ will look for all parents
    }
    controllerAs: 'taxiCard'
})
```

html:

```
<div ng-click="taxiCard.TaxiesController.cancelTaxi(taxi, id)"></div>
```

---

Or place all your functions from `TaxiesController` inside a service, and add it as a dependency to your `taxiCard` component:

```
.component('taxiCard', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/taxi.html',
    controllerAs: 'taxiCard',
    controller: function(taxiesService) {
        this.cancelTaxi = (taxi, id) => {
            taxiesService.cancelTaxi(taxi, id);
        }
    }
})
```

template:

```
<div ng-click="taxiCard.cancelTaxi(taxi, id)"></div>
```

---

*Protip: Please use the `controllerAs` syntax, and try to avoid `$scope` where possible.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will attempt this by converting the controller into a component.

Comment: Let me know. I’ve had the same issue a couple of days ago, and managed to solve it. So I’m sure I can help you out.

Comment: Alright, I've put the functions in a service and added them as a dependence, however the function is still not being called (console.log doesn't display anything). Here's the codepen of the edited code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRWVNY

Comment: I just removed the two-way data binding: cancelTaxi: '=' and it started working. Could you, please, explain why?

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake, I just copied it from your example. I think: by binding `cancelTaxi`, it creates the reference `this.cancelTaxi`. Next, in your controller, you create the function `this.cancelTaxi`. Therefor one overwrites the other. I think the binding 'wins', so your function is overwritten/lost. I think you can add the binding again, and just give your function a different name, and they work both.